# Display XML with XPath

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath

I just started using XML, and i have a form where the user adds some information, and is saved into an XML, this is the code to do it, it working fine:

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"CodeBehind="DatosFinancieros.aspx.cs"
Inherits="Tablero.DatosFinancieros" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<script runat="server">
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string xmlPath = MapPath("Datos/DatosFinancieros.xml");
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    //Check if the file already exists or not
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(xmlPath))
    {
        doc.Load(xmlPath);
        XmlNode DatosNodo = CreateDatosNodo(doc);
        //Get reference to the Datos node and append the Datos node to it
        XmlNode DatosFinancierosNodo = doc.SelectSingleNode("DatosFinancieros");
        DatosFinancierosNodo.AppendChild(DatosNodo);
        lblResult.Text = "El documento ha sido actualizado";
    }
    else
    {            
        XmlNode declarationNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "", "");
        doc.AppendChild(declarationNode);
        XmlNode comment = doc.CreateComment("Este archivo representa un fragmento de lo almacenado");
        doc.AppendChild(comment);            
        XmlNode DatosFinancierosNodo = doc.CreateElement("DatosFinancieros");
        XmlNode DatosNodo = CreateDatosNodo(doc);                        
        //Append the datos node to the DatosFinancieros node            
        DatosFinancierosNodo.AppendChild(DatosNodo);
        //Append the DatosFinancieros node to the document
        doc.AppendChild(DatosFinancierosNodo);
        lblResult.Text = "El documento ha sido creado";
    }
    doc.Save(xmlPath);
}
XmlNode CreateDatosNodo(XmlDocument doc)
{
XmlNode datosNodo = doc.CreateElement("Datos");
// Add Neta Mensual attribute to the Datos Node
XmlAttribute NetaMensualAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("NetaMensual");
NetaMensualAttribute.Value = txtNetaMensual.Text;
datosNodo.Attributes.Append(NetaMensualAttribute);

XmlAttribute NetaAcumuladoAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("NetaAcumulado");
NetaAcumuladoAttribute.Value = txtNetaAcumulado.Text;
datosNodo.Attributes.Append(NetaAcumuladoAttribute);

XmlAttribute MensualAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Mensual");
MensualAttribute.Value = txtMensual.Text;
datosNodo.Attributes.Append(MensualAttribute);

XmlAttribute AcumuladoAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Acumulado");
AcumuladoAttribute.Value = txtAcumulado.Text;
datosNodo.Attributes.Append(AcumuladoAttribute);

XmlAttribute LiquidezAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Liquidez");
LiquidezAttribute.Value = txtLiquidez.Text;
datosNodo.Attributes.Append(LiquidezAttribute);

XmlAttribute AccionMensualAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("AccionMensual");
AccionMensualAttribute.Value = TextAccionMensual.Text;
datosNodo.Attributes.Append(AccionMensualAttribute);

XmlAttribute AccionAcumuladaAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("AccionAcumulada");
AccionAcumuladaAttribute.Value = TextAccionAcumulada.Text;
datosNodo.Attributes.Append(AccionAcumuladaAttribute);

return datosNodo;
}

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width: 200px; height: 40px">
                <b style="font-size: x-large">Datos Financieros</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width: 174px; height: 40px">
                <b>Utilidad Neta/Capital</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 101px; height: 44px">
                Mensual:
            </td>
            <td style="width: 204px; height: 44px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNetaMensual" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 101px; height: 44px">
                Acumulado:
            </td>
            <td style="width: 204px; height: 44px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNetaAcumulado" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width: 174px; height: 40px">
                <b>Utilidad Neta/Ventas</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 101px; height: 41px">
                Mensual:
            </td>
            <td style="width: 204px; height: 41px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMensual" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 101px; height: 41px">
                Acumulado:
            </td>
            <td style="width: 204px; height: 41px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAcumulado" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 101px; height: 41px">
                Liquidez:
            </td>
            <td style="width: 204px; height: 41px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLiquidez" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width: 174px; height: 40px">
                <b>Acción</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 101px; height: 41px">
                Mensual:
            </td>
            <td style="width: 204px; height: 41px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextAccionMensual" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 101px; height: 41px">
                Acumulada:
            </td>
            <td style="width: 204px; height: 41px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextAccionAcumulada" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width: 101px; height: 41px">
                <asp:Button Text="Guardar" runat="server" ID="btnSave" Width="95px" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width: 101px; height: 41px">
                <asp:Label Text="Guardar" runat="server" ID="lblResult" Width="295px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
    </html>
```

Now, i want to display that information on this form, i have this made, is running. doesn't give me any errors but doesn't display anything, just the blank screen:

```
    <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" XPath="datos" DataFile="Datos/DatosFinancieros.xml" />
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <hr />
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("datos") %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    Neto Mensual:
                    <%# XPath("NetaMensual") %>
                    <br />
                    Neta Acumulado:
                    <%# XPath("NetaAcumulado") %>
                    <br />
                    <hr />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</div>
</form>
```

Anyone has an idea what i'm doing wrong so the information isn't displayed??? Sorry for the long post but is to give a better idea of what i'm doing!

Comment: Where is btnSave defined - I see the event handler but no tag for it?

Comment: 2nd one from the bottom to the top!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code for your screen and see if the XML is appearing.

If it does appear, then the problem is that HTML is a variant of XML and browsers interpret anything with XML-style tags as markup rather than info.

You need to HTML-encode your XML within the <%# %> tags.

```
<%# Server.HtmlEncode(XPath(xyz)) %>
```

Comment: where i put this?? on the first code i paste or directly into the XML file??

Comment: I notice that you use a relative path for your Datos directory.  Is it possible that your new page can't find it?

Comment: @Ivelisse  On your second code section, in the HTML.  Where you are saying `<%# XPath("something") %>`, put instead `<%# Server.HtmlEncode(XPath("something")) %>`

Comment: Gives me an error: Server Error in '/' Application. Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. Was on this line: <%# Server.HtmlEncode(XPath("NetaMensual")) %>